# Not understanding Scipy Optimize with Nonlinear constraints

Tags: scipy-optimize, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to optimise a function f with input m,n,a,b for fixed values of a and b. I want values of m and n as output. The constraints are that 1>n>m>0. I've tried implementing this, but I'm really struggling to understand how the NonlinearConstraint function works.

This is my code:

```
import math
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import NonlinearConstraint


# defines the free-energy function with z=1
def f(m,n,a,b):
    return -1/2(m**2 + a**2*n**2) + a**2*n + 1/b*((n+m)/2*math.log(1/2(n+m)) 
                                                  + (n-m)/2*math.log(1/2(n-m)) + (1-n)*math.log(1-n))


# defines function that minimises L for fixed a,b. Returns n and m.
def minimiser(f,a,b,m0,n0):
    def f2(m,n):
        return f(m,n,a,b)
    con = lambda x: x[1]-x[0] 
    cons = NonlinearConstraint(con,0,2)
    return minimize(f2, (m0,n0), bounds=((0,1),(0,1)), constraints=cons).OptimizeResult
```

However, using the minimiser function, Python returns "f2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'". I understand that con requires a single input and f2 requires two. However, if I change part of the code to the following:

```
# defines function that minimises L for fixed a,b. Returns n and m.
def minimiser(f,a,b,m0,n0):
    def f2(x):
        return f(x[0],x[1],a,b)
    con = lambda x: x[1]-x[0] 
    cons = NonlinearConstraint(con,0,2)
    return minimize(f2, (m0,n0), bounds=((0.0,1.0),(0.0,1.0)), constraints=cons).OptimizeResult
```

then it returns that "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable". This error occurs in the definition of f. These might be completely unrelated errors, but I'm so confused that I don't know what I'm doing anymore. I've looked at a lot of posts on nonlinear optimisation, but the level is slightly too high for me to understand what is happening.

Comment: It should be `-1/2*(m**2 ....)` instead of `-1/2(m**2 ...)`. The integer literal `2` is an integer and thus `2(...)` is interpreted as a function call, which doesn't work as the `2` is no function obviously.

Comment: Your "con" seems linear, not non-linear.